# ESLint error and warning for the same rule with different options

Tags: configuration, eslint

Is there a way to configure ESLint's [`no-unused-vars`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) rule to show unused variables as errors except if they are function args show them as warnings?

Something like:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "none" }],
        "no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "vars": "none", "args": "all" }],
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of eslint that they do not feel the need to fix. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11089

Comment: This question seems duplicate of this. Someone even suggested workaround for your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077756/including-both-errors-and-warnings-for-same-eslint-rule